# Is there an easier way to find correlations between categorical data and multiple column of numerical data in R?

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data

I am looking for correlations between categorical data and numerical scores from a survey in RStudio.  I am still learning R and was able to figure out a way to assign numbers to categories from my survey and compare them to a single column of data at a time.  However, this has proven rather tedious.  Is there a simpler way to create a table that compares the original categorical data now in Column1 to several columns of data in an excel file instead?

```r
df <- read.table(text=" x
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Expert; has broad influence and experience within organization'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Expert; has broad influence and experience within organization'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Expert; has broad influence and experience within organization'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Expert; has broad influence and experience within organization'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Expert; has broad influence and experience within organization'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
'Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise'
'Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals'
           ",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

```r
library(dplyr)
column1=df%>%
  mutate(x=case_when(
    .$x=="Seasoned Professional; with a variety of technical skills developed; strong problem solver" ~ 1,
    .$x=="Entry-level; learning technical and professional skills" ~ 2,
    .$x=="Early career; with basic skills development; work contributes to the success of team goals" ~ 3,
    .$x=="Advanced; very senior; can solve most problems of issues that arise" ~ 4,
    .$x=="Expert; has broad influence and experience within organization" ~ 5
  ))
column2=read.table(file.choose(),sep=",",header=TRUE)
data=data.frame(c(column1,column2))
mydata.cor = cor(data, method = c("spearman"))
```

Comment: Careful: *"assign numbers"* suggests ordinality in your data, which is unclear (and often not wholly the case). If you assign a number, you are assigning a relative value, meaning the string to which you assign `4` is either twice the value or occurs much after string string to which you assign `2`. It's hard to comment further without seeing your numeric data; can you post the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative sample of `data`, perhaps the top 20 or so rows?

Comment: OK, thank you.  I see what you mean.  You are correct, there is not ordinality in this data.  I am looking for correlations so I am assigning numbers to multiple choice answers here and comparing it to Likert scale results.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a string into a categorical number is exactly what `factor()` does:

```r
library(dplyr)

column1 = df %>%
  mutate(x=factor(x))
```